# Insert into table gives different results

Tags: sql, view, insert, databricks

I inserted all the rows of a view to a delta table, but after running a query for a particular value I get below results.
Can someone explain to me how this is possible?

A is View and B is Delta(databricks) table.

1.

```
Select count(*) from A
```

result: 102.321

2.

```
Select * from A where id = '11'
```

| id | date | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2022-09-02 | 4 |

3.

```
Insert Into B Select * From A
```

OR

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE B AS ( SELECT * FROM A)
```

4. 

```
Select count(*) from B '
```

result: 101.372

5.

```
Select * from B where id = '11'
```

| id | date | unit |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 2022-09-02 | 2 |

Comment: Show the view and what do you mean by "delta tabel"

Comment: did you delete all the records out of B before step 3?  Also we need to see the definition of the table -- it is easy to have this happen with a calculated column

Comment: Yes I created a new table. you are right, it is calculated column. I simplified here. ROUND(SUM(sales),2) unit

Instead of insert, I also used another query but still get similar results.
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE B
AS ( SELECT * FROM A);

Comment: So during the insert there were less rows in the table when the sum was calculated in table B than in table A